# ORA-009906: Missing left parenthesis error?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote this CREATE SQL query, but when I try running it, I get this 'missing left parenthesis' error (ORA-009906), even though it doesn't look like I'm missing any, and I've been staring at the query for a whole hour trying to figure it out. I use ORACLE SQL Developer to create my queries.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (driver_license  VARCHAR2(20),
                        SSN             NUMBER(10,0),
                        first_name      VARCHAR2(20),
                        last_name       VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
                        birth_date      DATE,
                        hire_date       DATE, -- The hire_date corresponds to when the employee is *first* hired.-- 
                        state           CHAR(2 BYTE)     DEFAULT 'UD',
                        CONSTRAINT ssn_pk PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
                        CHECK (hire_date > birth_date),
                        UNIQUE driver_license,
                        INDEX state_index);
```

Comment: Are there any other queries in your sheet that could be corrupting this one? Have you tried deleting the comment? Are you sure all of the commas on your constraints and checks are necessary and placed correctly?

Comment: @Marc i removed the comment , and still got the same error. This query is the only one on the file.

Comment: Why did you tag MySQL and SQL Server if you are using Oracle?

Comment: @Marc unless I'm missing something, I assume all the commas are added correctly

Comment: @SMor sorry, first time using stackoverflow, tried to use any tags that could help

Comment: Do you use Oracle SQL Developer to _create_ your queries, or also to _run_ your queries? Because if you run your queries in another environment/your code, maybe there is a slightly different syntax, depending on the driver/framework being used? E.g. the trailing `;` might be an issue or something like that.

Comment: I'm skeptical about your `INDEX state_index` syntax. Try removing that and creating the index independently.

Comment: I haven't understood what you tried to achieve in the last line `index state_index`? I don't see state_index in column list and it doesn't look like you wanted to give such name to the index for unique constraint

Comment: @UweKeim i am running queries on Oracle SQL Developer. I am trying to create a table with the query mentioned above. I attempted to remove the trailer but it had no effect. The error states that there is a missing paranthesis...

Comment: @Marc just tried removing the index, still the same error being displayed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table (driver_license  VARCHAR2(20),
                        SSN             NUMBER(10,0),
                        first_name      VARCHAR2(20),
                        last_name       VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
                        birth_date      DATE,
                        hire_date       DATE, -- The hire_date corresponds to when the employee is *first* hired.-- 
                        state           CHAR(2 BYTE)     DEFAULT 'UD',
                        CONSTRAINT ssn_pk PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
                        Constraint ssn_chk CHECK (hire_date > birth_date),
                        Constraint ssn_uq UNIQUE(driver_license) 
);
```

If you want to create also index on (state), you should use separate DDL command:

```
Create index ssn_state_ix on new_table (state) ;
```